# SuiteCRM edit lead module html and js errors

Tags: php, suitecrm

When trying to change the fields to be displayed within a Lead, the edit panels generate errors and I don't understand why. 
The development console says it's missing images, but I don't understand why it destroys html...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks to those who can help me!

Comment: images take some room in a page. if you don't specify their size in the html the browser will not be able to calculate the room they occupy when not found

Comment: I didn't change the original code, what blows up the size of the images?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a .htaccess or folder permission problem.

If you are using apache make sure the generated .htaccess file has the right permissions.

You can (linux) quickly fix your permissions with this bash command (make sure to update apache user in the last command, its set to apache user used by centos/redhat, for ubuntu change to www-data)

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \; &&  find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \; 
chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload  config_override.php  config.php
chown -R apache:apache .
```

Comment: changing the permissions to the folders and files contained in them I see the same errors

Comment: did u run repair and rebuild after that?

Comment: yes, the process starts and then ends generating an error, I solved overwriting custom folders and modules

Comment: ok, if repair and rebuild doesn't work definetely something with permissions/ownership